# How to "streamify" functions in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stream

Say I have a function that returns something:

```
function f(thing){
    //do stuff
    return result;
}
```

If there are instances where I want to use this function as the `transform()` function in the transform stream, I can "streamify" it by using a function similar to `util.promisify()`:

```
function streamify(func){
    return function(chunk, encoding, callback){
        this.push(func(chunk));
        callback();
    }
}
```

But say I have a class, which contains an object representing a resource, and I want to use a method of that class in a stream. For example:

```
class c {
    constructor(args){
        this.resource = new SomeResource(args.something);
    }
    classMethod(thing){
        //do stuff
        this.resource.func();
        //do more stuff
        return result;
    }
}
```

If I simply pass the function to the stream constructor, or even use my `streamify()` above, when the function is called `this` is referencing the stream, not the class, so the function generates an error since `this.resource` doesn't exist in that context. I could do something like this:

```
someStream.resource = myClass.resrouce;
```

But I was always under the impression that directly modifying the prototypes like that was frowned upon.

I'm looking to see if there's a way to accomplish this without having to extend the Stream classes and implement an entirely new class. That just seems like overkill just to be able to use 1 function from either a 3rd-party library or my own in the context of a transform stream.